# Inductor Coupling Question

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism

I want to prove that a voltage signal I apply in the primary of an ideal transformer(or 2 coupled coils) will produce the same voltage signal in the secondary, e.g. a square wave(+- V) in the primary yielding a square wave in the secondary by using the fact that V=L*(di/dt).

So let´s suppose I have a square wave generator. At the moment the square wave reaches +V then V=L1* (di1/dt) and the current I1 in the primary ramps up linearly, causing then V/(L1)*t = i(t), and that means (di1/dt) = V/L1.

This increasing current will then create a magnetic field B= k1 * i(t), where k1 is a constant and the induced voltage in the secondary is going to be V2= -(d(phi)/dt) = - k1 * (di1/dt) = -k1 * (V/L1).

The outcome shows the secondary is going to have the same wave shape signal as the primary, which in this case is a square wave. So assuming I have a V(t) applied to this ideal transformer, the secondary signal is going to be the proportional to this V(t).

Finally, my question is: Can I prove the secondary signal will be alike the the primary by the way I did above? Which is by using the inductor formula V=L*(di/dt)?

Comment: The copy-voltage from input-to-output of a 1:1 ratio transformer depends upon the near-perfect cancellation in the core, of primary-winding flux being bucked (opposed) by the secondary-winding flux. Some tiny resistance in the voltage source powering the primary (or some tiny impedance at the frequency of interest) is needed; the tiny resistance/impedance implements a HUGE SERVO-LOOP REGULATION action. The core summation provides the negative-feedback behavior. Want a poor transformer? Add a large source impedance.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I think your comment is valid for a **real** transformer but the question asks about an **ideal** transformer. The common model of an **ideal** transformer cares only about the turns ratio and not resistance or second-order effects.

Answer (score 0):

**Ideal Transformer** 
By Faraday's law of induction:

Vs = − Ns dΦ / dt 
Vp = − Np dΦ / dt

Where V is the instantaneous voltage, N is the number of turns in a winding, dΦ/dt is the derivative of the magnetic flux Φ through one turn of the winding over time (t), and subscripts p and s indicate primary and secondary.

Combining the ratio of equations 1 and 2:
Turns ratio = Vp/Vs = −Np/−Ns

Now to your question: 
You can not simply determine i1 with the inductor equation V1=L*(di1/dt) on the primary side because i1 is also dependent on the magnetic flux through both windings and i2 on the secondary side. Also, L2 is missing in your equations.

Comment: An ideal square wave alternates between two constant values. But a transformer only generates induced emf's in response to changing inputs, and the only changes are the instantaneous transitions between constant values. So a square wave output will not be achieved. To produce a square output, the input current needs to be triangular.

Comment: @Chu I think the critical issue is that the OP asked about an **ideal** transformer and the common definition of an ideal transformer says that the voltage ratio is equal to the turns ratio at **any** frequency, including dc. I agree, however, that this definition has very limited usability.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson,  I’d like to see the definition that says an ideal transformer will work at DC.

Comment: @Chu Try Wikipedia, as most students will. The "ideal transformer identity" does not include frequency as a factor; it states that the ratio of voltages is equal to the turns ratio. You can argue that this does not imply operation at dc, but it does imply operation at 0.000...01 Hz which is effectively dc in my book. Find the "Ideal Transformer" page at www.mathworks.com and you will learn that the model can also be used for an ideal DC-DC converter. I could cite many other sources but you only asked for one. I didn't say I was happy about it, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, the wikipedia article on the ideal transformer starts by saying '... A varying current in the transformer's primary winding creates a varying magnetic flux in the transformer core...'. Clearly, DC is not varying.

Comment: @Chu Again, as I said, the current could be varying at 0.00...01 Hz which is effectively dc, and the time-varying term cancels so that the final result has no frequency term. You have to read through to the conclusion. Also, the mathworks page?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, but we're talking about 'ideal' here, so however small you make the frequency, it is not DC.

Comment: @Chu Seriously, you want to quibble about whether 0.00...01 Hz is "effectively" dc? Also, the mathworks page?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, as soon as you use the word 'ideal', DC means 0 Hz. Rate of change of flux is zero, induced emf is zero.

Comment: @Chu Also, the mathworks page? Mathematically, \$0.\overline{9} = 1\$ so \$0.0...01 = 1 - 0.\overline{9} = 0\$

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, ok, so you're saying that if I apply 10 V DC to an ideal 1:1 transformer, I will get 10 V DC out? Also, If you replace '=' with ' \$\small \rightarrow\$' in your expressions then I totally agree with them. However, that doesn't change the fact that zero changing flux = zero induced emf.

Comment: @Chu The **ideal transformer model** says that the ratio of primary and secondary voltages is the same as the turns ratio. Period. So, yes, a 1:1 ideal transformer has a secondary voltage equal to the primary voltage. Also, the mathworks page?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson A dc signal is applied into an inductor, which yields a current linearly time dependent, so di/dt is constant and in an ideal model it should work, shouldn't it?. Also, I mentioned the usage of a square wave, which in a real model, say we have a ferrite core transformer being set to receive the square wave in a particular frequency not to reach the primary inductor´s terminal current will cause a secondary voltage during this small ramp to be a square wave as well, otherwise a dc-dc converter like a flyback would not work, since its powered by a train pulse, am I wrong on that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "should work". All models are wrong, some are useful...said George Box. The ideal model is an extremely simple model that cares nothing about dt. This model is not useful for analyzing the behavior of a **real** transformer with a square wave on the primary. BTW, with an ideal dc voltage source connected in parallel with an ideal inductor the current would be infinite and di/dt would be zero.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Anyway I've just performed a test in a usual 127/18V 60Hz transformer, and the results came out as expected. I inserted a square wave and it yielded a square wave in the output, then a triangular wave and the output showed a triangular too, both applied in 60Hz. If I increased the frequency or decreased surely I would see different results, which I'm not sure now. I was not expecting the signal to follow all the equations correctly, just wanted to see the output being the same as the input. Thank you for your help, it made me understand better.